# What is the Most Efficient Way to Calculate the Internal Rate of Return IRR?

Tags: programming, pricing, asset-pricing, pricing-formulae

I have built a program that prices financial assets and it does this in part by calculating the IRR. The problem is that it does not run as quickly as I would like it to.

I currently use the Newton-Raphson method of calculating roots of equations, but then switch to the Interval Bisection method after a set number of tries. This is because there is a chance that the Newton-Raphson method cannot find the IRR, for instance, due to asymptotes. My understanding is that the Newton-Raphson method is more efficient for the cases that it actually works with, which is why my system is currently set up like this.

Is there a more efficient formula or algorithm that I can use to calculate the IRR of a financial asset than the ones that I am currently employing? Or, if there is none, is there a way I can change my current order of calculations to make it more efficient?

If you are in need of any of the formulas that I use to actually be written in this question, please let me know. Thank you for your time.

**Update**

The pricing software that I have designed is a PHP extension written in the C language. This is because it is a web based program. I cannot change languages due to reasons to do with the company that I work for, so, despite them being good suggestions, I cannot use PERL or the Excel IRR function. I didn't mention the languages before as I didn't think that they were too important due to the fact that I am looking for an increase in mathematical efficiency, not computational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Brent's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method), it works well.

Comment: I have been looking at this and it potentially could be the best solution. I think I will implement this and then do some speed tests, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with calculating an IRR for a couple of weeks now. I have implemented 5 different methods and have come to the conclusion that [Halley's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) is the most efficient (in my case, using Python) thus far. Brent's method works pretty well too!

Denote the Net Present value function as $P(r)$. We know that finding the IRR requires finding $r_{*} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(r_{*}) = 0$.

Since $P(r)$ is a polynomial, we can take advantage of utilizing the second derivative. According to Wikipedia, we obtain cubic convergence as opposed to Newton-Raphson's quadratic (in general) convergence.

Answer (score 0):

No reputation for comments (sorry).  What programming language / libraries are you using?

I think that the Excel library just does 20 iterations.

You might find it useful to look at the Perl module [Finance::Math::IRR](http://search.cpan.org/~erwan/Finance-Math-IRR-0.10/lib/Finance/Math/IRR.pm)  That particular library uses a secant method.  The Gnumeric gnumeric.org apparently uses Newton's.

There is a very short paper by [Moten & Thron](http://www.ceser.in/ceserp/index.php/ijamas/article/view/1929) that offers an improvment to the secant method that they claim is more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question to let you know what technology that I am using. I'll take a look at the Secant method, thanks for that.

Comment: Also, how much do you know about the Secant method? Do you how efficient it is in comparison to the Newton-Raphson method or the Interval Bisection method?

Comment: The question on language/library was not meant to suggest changing anything.  Even when you have very compelling reasons to write a routine from scratch it is helpful to use a reference model to verify your results and to make sure that your performance is reasonable.

Comment: As a gross generalization, the Secant method is probably a bit faster than Newton-Raphson.  However, as a general method for finding roots it is not guaranteed.  Brent's method, as suggested by experquiste is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

By mixing multiple approaches I came up with algorithm that does not need guess as an input. I focused on custom precision and resiliency. Please take a look.

https://medium.com/@manchikanti/irr-internal-rate-of-return-calculator-15ec269bd8f5?source=friends_link&sk=21cc51cc485647cb73eb0a66c57522bd

https://chitbazaar.github.io/kautilya/